# Selenium 3/TestNG giving N/A test result

Tags: java, selenium

I've recently upgraded to Selenium 3.141.59 from 2.47.0. Since the upgrade, our test suites have been receiving random N/A test results. It happens to about 1% of the tests and I have not been able to track down any meaningful logs to determine the cause.

We're using Selenium Grid Extras as our distribution.

Here is what a report looks like:
[image: testng report]

I am able to see that the test is being sent to the node by the hub:

```
14 Mar 2019 15:03:31 [pool-1-thread-291] INFO  threads.SessionHistoryCallable  - Notifying Remote Grid Extras node of new session with http://1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/grid_status?session=3e317470-0535-436d-8a70-02e43daff160

The only error I see in the Grid extras log is that the video callable fails out with the following error:

java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.HttpUtility.getRequest(HttpUtility.java:60)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.HttpUtility.getRequestAsString(HttpUtility.java:35)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.HttpUtility.getRequestAsString(HttpUtility.java:29)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.HttpUtility.getRequestAsString(HttpUtility.java:25)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.videorecording.RemoteVideoRecorderHelper.updateLastAction(RemoteVideoRecorderHelper.java:109)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.threads.video.RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.updateLastAction(RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.java:112)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.threads.video.RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.call(RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.java:65)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.threads.video.RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.call(RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.java:11)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
14 Mar 2019 15:03:31 [Forwarding ext. key 3e317470-0535-436d-8a70-02e43daff160 to http://1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555/wd/hub at 3:03:31 PM] INFO  video.RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable  - Creating new Video callable for proxy: http://1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5555, int key: 6a00e694-c2d2-47fd-807c-3bd23124810f, ex. key: 3e317470-0535-436d-8a70-02e43daff160, action: heartbeat, lastAction: /session/3e317470-0535-436d-8a70-02e43daff160/alert/text: 
14 Mar 2019 15:03:31 [pool-1-thread-283] ERROR videorecording.RemoteVideoRecorderHelper  - Error building URI for host: 1xx.xxx.xxx.xxx, port: 3000, session: 3e317470-0535-436d-8a70-02e43daff160, action: heartbeat, params: {session=3e317470-0535-436d-8a70-02e43daff160, action=heartbeat, description=/session/3e317470-0535-436d-8a70-02e43daff160/alert/text: }
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.HttpUtility.getRequest(HttpUtility.java:60)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.HttpUtility.getRequestAsString(HttpUtility.java:35)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.HttpUtility.getRequestAsString(HttpUtility.java:29)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.HttpUtility.getRequestAsString(HttpUtility.java:25)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.videorecording.RemoteVideoRecorderHelper.updateLastAction(RemoteVideoRecorderHelper.java:109)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.threads.video.RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.updateLastAction(RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.java:112)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.threads.video.RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.call(RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.java:65)
    at com.groupon.seleniumgridextras.utilities.threads.video.RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.call(RemoteVideoRecordingControlCallable.java:11)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am at a complete loss and have not been able to find other with the N/A test result. Any help would be appreciated.